Will I be unable to unite with the Lord Krishna if I follow Advaitic teachings?
I have been tortured by this dilemma for quite a while now. On the one hand, I feel intellectually drawn to Advaita Vedanta. I read and deliberate routinely on Ramana Maharshi's teachings. On the other hand, I am way too emotionally attached to Lord Krishna to be at peace with the possibility that I might never unite with Him if I merge into Brahman (realize Advaita). I was raised a Vaishnava, so I am aware that our philosophy criticizes Advaita and advocates Bhakti to Lord Hari. Some even warn that Advaita is dangerous and might permanently (like eternity level permanent) get one banished from Vaikuntha.
I was wondering if there were scriptures or verses from the Bhagavad Gita which indicate that the two paths are indeed contradictory. Guru Ramana Maharshi, however, dismisses this idea and claims that the two paths are indeed one and the same. Speaking from personal experience, it just doesn't seem so, no matter how hard I try.
In the end, what matters to me the most is my ultimate union with my beloved Lord. I was wondering if I could follow Advaita and Ramana Maharshi, but still unite with Lord Krishna in the end.

@Why don't you sincerely pray to Lord Krishna and see what happens?

Advaita says, Bhakti and Karma lead to purification if mind, which leads to jnana. Adherence to jnana is moksha. So, Krishna Bhakti doesn't stop one realising Brahma, it's a path.


OP: Will I be unable to unite with the Lord Krishna if I follow Advaitic teachings?

Yes. Why not?

But those who fully worship the unmanifested, that which lies beyond
the perception of the senses, the all-pervading, inconceivable,
unchanging, fixed and immovable – the impersonal conception of the
Absolute Truth – by controlling the various senses and being equally
disposed to everyone, such persons, engaged in the welfare of all, at
last achieve Me.
For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifested, impersonal
feature of the Supreme, advancement is very troublesome. To make
progress in that discipline is always difficult for those who are
embodied.
BG 12.3-5


Advaita says you are Lord Hari..Are you lord Hari?
Was Osama bin laden Lord Hari?
Do you think lord of universe is crazy so he did this lila of horrible samsara full of pain and suffering..
If i break your finger and say dont worry it is all lila then what will you say?
If you are lord hari then why you cannot free yourself from maya in a trice?
Will you jump in a pond full of crocodiles and say it is my leela?
The world is real prabhu we are trapped in samsara since anadi due to swarupa ajnana..lord does not want anything..he just fulfils jivas desire and rewards fruits according to karma..it is His upakara that he delivers suffering souls..those who surrender to Him are saved from Maya.
Avyaktam vyaktim apannam iti manyante mām abuddhayaḥ
paraṁ bhāvam ajānanto
mamāvyayam anuttamam
Unintelligent men, who do not know Me perfectly, think that I, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, was impersonal before and have now assumed this personality. Due to their small knowledge, they do not know My higher nature, which is imperishable and supreme.
So lord is a person..there are many references which state lord is different from jiva eternally(na tv evāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ
na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ) in the sense that we are lords amsha(mamaivamso jiva loke) and energy(anyas tu prakruti me param) hence jiva is also bramha(achintya bhedabheda)..there are 5 types of mukti sayujya salokya sarupya samipya and sarasti..So I strongly recommend you to read Bhagavad Gita as it is by Srila Prabhupada so that philosophy becomes clear.It has many scriptural references which refute Advaita..

Yoga is a ladder of four steps
https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%97_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE

The advaita realization stage being the highest is debatable. Śrimad Bhāgavatam totally rejects it actually and is called the primary stage of God realization. It has many parallels to Patanjali's Citta-vṛtti-nirodhaḥ state and as such, not the highest state one can have.
Don't forget that Veda-vyāsa had svarūpa experience (the same thing Advaita tries hard to get) but was still uncomfortable and dissatisfied, before he had the darśana of bhagavān and wrote about his glories.
Bhaktas acknowledge that you can have the experience of your own svarūpa but they totally reject it. What is the experience of this puny little svarūpa compared to the whole ocean of bliss that is bhagavān? Jīva Gosvāmi writes that the experience of merging into your own nature (Brahman) is like water trapped in the hoof print of a calf, compared to the whole ocean, i.e. Bhagavān/Para-brahman.
Krishna never once says that the world is false, Advaita injects its own opinion in there. Krishna never says you become one with him, Advaita injects its own opinion there.
One cannot follow Advaita and still be a Krishna bhakta. That kind of bhakti is called jñana-miṣrit bhakti, where you use bhagavān as a prop to gain another thing, not bhagavān.
If you're actually interested in Advaita, consider looking into Śuddhadvaita and Viśiṣtadvaita.
I'd suggest reading more about the pūrva-pakśa of Advaita, especially since you lean towards Vaiṣṇavism.
There's plenty of intellectual stimulation in Vaiṣṇava theology. You can watch videos by Satyanarayana Das from Jiva Institute of Vedic Studies, lectures on Indian philosophy by Edwin Braynt.
I recommend watching this lecture by Professor Edwin Bryant: https://youtube.com/watch?v=l1dE0B1AEIA
I hope this helps! Hare Krishna

Yes, the impersonal brahman, the svarūpa of the ātman is not the goal of the bhaktas because there is no love involved. It's a static experience, the world still exists when you're invested in your svarūpa, God still exists out there and that is what bhaktas seek.

The advaitin says that everything is Brahman. In the Bhagavad Gita, Bhagavan Krishna says this -

bahūnāṅ janmanāmantē jñānavānmāṅ prapadyatē.
vāsudēvaḥ sarvamiti sa mahātmā sudurlabhaḥ৷৷7.19৷৷


7.19 At the end of many births the man of Knowledge attains Me, (realizing) that Vasudeva is all. Such a high-souled one is very rare.

The statement "vAsudevaH sarvam", is like "sarvam khalvidam brahma" (from chhAndogya upanishad) or "everything is indeed brahman" - one of the mahAvAkyas in advaita.
Bhagavan Himself is saying that one comes to the advaitic realization that Brahman/Vasudeva is everything and attains Him (Krishna).
Also, just before the above sloka, Bhagavan distinguishes four classes of devotees and praises a jnAni as the best devotee.

caturvidhā bhajantē māṅ janāḥ sukṛtinō.rjuna.
ārtō jijñāsurarthārthī jñānī ca bharatarṣabha৷৷7.16৷৷


7.16 O Arjuna, foremost of the Bharata dynasty, four classes of people of virtuous deeds adore Me: the afflicted, the seeker of Knowledge, the seeker of wealth and the man of Knowledge.


tēṣāṅ jñānī nityayukta ēkabhakitarviśiṣyatē.
priyō hi jñāninō.tyarthamahaṅ sa ca mama priyaḥ৷৷7.17৷৷


7.17 Of them, the man of Knowledge, endowed with constant steadfastness and one-pointed devotion, excels. For I am very much dear to the man of Knowledge, and he too is dear to Me.

Above sloka also implies that bhakti and jnAna are not contradictory paths.

udārāḥ sarva ēvaitē jñānī tvātmaiva mē matam.
āsthitaḥ sa hi yuktātmā māmēvānuttamāṅ gatim৷৷7.18৷৷


7.18 All of these, indeed, are noble, but the man of Knowledge is the very Self. (This is) My opinion. For, with a steadfast mind, he is set on the path leading to Me alone who am the super-excellent Goal.

The Lord loves a jnAni.
